What is /etc/pam.d/other actually do?
What is /etc/pam.d/other actually do?
The content of the file is:
auth     required       pam_deny.so
account  required       pam_deny.so
password required       pam_deny.so
session  required       pam_deny.so


Did you search Google or look in the man pages or do any research?

/etc/pam.d/other is a catch-all for PAM configurations. It is used when an application or service does not have a specific PAM configuration file in /etc/pam.d/
From https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/tree/debian/local/other?h=ubuntu/jammy in jammy (22.04)
#
# /etc/pam.d/other - specify the PAM fallback behaviour
#
# Note that this file is used for any unspecified service; for example
#if /etc/pam.d/cron  specifies no session modules but cron calls
#pam_open_session, the session module out of /etc/pam.d/other is
#used.  If you really want nothing to happen then use pam_permit.so or
#pam_deny.so as appropriate.

# We fall back to the system default in /etc/pam.d/common-*
# 

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
@include common-session

